# show shop instead of 404 page for missing products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, 404-error, nginx

How should I show the shop instead of a 404 page when a product is missing? Currently users get a 404 page which makes them loose interest.

I use woocommerce with wordpress on a server with nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`// Missing product redirect to product category
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function( $rules )
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'shop/([^/]*?)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'shop/([^/]*?)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]',
    );
    return $new_rules + $rules;
} );`